# Visual Studio 2015: WindowsXamlDiagnosticsTap exception

Tags: visual-studio, exception, windows-runtime, windows-phone, visual-studio-2015

When I run a Windows Phone 10 project from Visual Studio 2015 then the following exception pops up after the second run:

```
Exception thrown at 0x61594533 (WindowsXamlDiagnosticsTap.dll) in remote.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.
```

The exception is raised in debug and release mode. Consecutive runs also fail with this exception. The only fix is to restart Visual Studio after each debug run.

Is there a way to disable this xaml debugging tap? Or what could be the reason for the exception?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

It might be this known issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsUIDevLabs/issues/75

Disable Live Visual Tree Debugging as a work around for now.